# How to access Pull queues on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have created a pull queue on gae. Now I am trying to access it from the Google API Explorer ( https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/rest/taskqueues/get)

However I get the following error:

```
403 Forbidden

- Show headers -

{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "forbidden",
"message": "you are not allowed to make this api call"
}
],
"code": 403,
"message": "you are not allowed to make this api call"
}
}
```

I have added my e-mail in the queue.xml file. And I have enabled the OAuth 2.0 authorization.

Any idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please double-check that you have spelled the queue name and the user e-mail address correctly.

Comment: I have even triple-checked it  :)